# observer.complete() not returning immediately

Tags: angular

Perhaps I am missing the point but I was under the impression observer.complete() would finish the observer i.e. statements after observer.complete() don't execute since it has completed.

```
 export class RecordsService {
   public getRecords(): Observable<any> {

let vm = this;

return new Observable(observer => {
    var records = vm.http.get(
    url).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log('we got data ', data);
      observer.next(data)
      observer.complete();
    });

    observer.next(null);
    observer.complete();
     });
   }
 }
```

I can see the console correctly but the subscriber is getting the data and null. How can i do that? I expected to get the data via observer.next(data) and the observer.next(null) wouldn't be executed since I have previously called observer.complete().

Now I am getting the data first then null, which I didn't expect

Comment: whats the behaviour you are expecting? and whats the `observer`?

Comment: @alt255 perhaps I got the explanation wrong but observer.next(data); observer.complete() would have for lack of a better word stopped further execution. I didn't expect null to be returned after observer.complete() is called.

Answer (score 2):

No other values will be emitted by an observer after it has completed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4cc25g

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const hello = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  observer.next('Hello');
  observer.complete();
  observer.next('World');
});

const subscribe = hello.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

You can see this demonstrated in the stackblitx example.

> I expected to get the data via observer.next(data) and the observer.next(null) wouldn't be executed since I have previously called observer.complete().

`observer.next(null)` is called **first** and the async HTTP calls `observer.next(data)` later, but the observer was already completed.

Comment: thanks @cgTag . Looking at my code, what would I have to do to have null to to be sent later on only if no data was sent?

Comment: @NieSelam that depends how no data was sent. Is it the result of a HTTP error or does the HTTP response contain no data?

Comment: @Reactgular can we complete without emitting any value .next i can see many places in my code repo that takeUntill(this.destroyed$)

  this.destroyed$.next(true);
   this.destroyed$.complete();